# How to position html <a> tag above an image and in the middle?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html (inside ASP.NET Repeater):

```
<div class="team_member">
    <a class="teamMemberLink" href='<%# "Profile.aspx?uID=" + Eval("ID") %>' target="_blank"><%# Eval("Name")%></a> 
    <asp:Image ID="teamMemberProfileImage" CssClass="teamMemberImg" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?id=" + Eval("ID") %>' />                                      
    <input id="rateTeamMember" class="teamMemberRating" type="button" value="" runat="server" />
    <input id="teamMemberID" type="hidden" value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
</div>
```

My problem is that I need the anchor's text to be exactly above the picture and at the middle.

Because the anchor's text is not a fixed length, how can I accomplish this when my image width is 96px?

How can I get the width in pixels of the anchor's text? 
If I would know it, I could position it using jQuery (setting the 'left' property, because i'm using 'position:relative').

EDIT - my css code:

```
.team_member { float: left; margin-left: 10%; margin-top: 10%; text-align:center; }
.teamMemberLink { float: left; clear: left; position: relative; top: -20px; }
.teamMemberImg { width: 96px; height: 96px; float: left; border: 1px solid #d1c7ac; }
.teamMemberRating { float: left; }
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can set teamMemberLink class to be of certain width and use margin:0 auto in css. If text is too long though it'll break in 2 or 3 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you have far too many unessential floats. I would change the CSS to the following:

```
.team_member { 
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 10%; 
    margin-top: 10%; 
    text-align:center; 
    width:96px; 
 }
.teamMemberLink { display:block; }
.teamMemberImg { 
    display:block; 
    width: 96px; 
    height: 96px; 
    border: 1px solid #d1c7ac; 
}
.teamMemberRating { display:block; }
```

Basically, to remain < IE8 compatible, the 'floating' team-member should really have a width set.

Setting `float:left;` on `.teamMemberLink` was breaking the alignment due to the float. I also removed a lot of uneeded `floats` from the CSS.

JS Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/NuSHQ/

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<div style="width: 96px; text-align: center;">
    <a href="#">stackoverflow</a><br />
    <img src="#" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it.  If it's not working for you, then start unwinding all of your floats and relative positions, which are likely unnecessary.

Comment: but the link can be longer than 96px - this is the problem... the link's text depends on the value from the database...

Comment: When I tested it I set the width of the div to be wider than the widest of the two elements, whether that be the anchor or the img tag. Now, if you want the div to be just as wide as it needs to be, but no wider, you may want some sort of JavaScript to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Whoa there, no need to jump into using javascript so quickly. If your image is a fixed length, why not set your anchor text to be a fixed length as well? If you're centering the text anyway, it won't effect how it is positioned, and it will solve any problem that you might have if the text is too long to fit on one line, since it will just wrap the extra to the next line.

```
a { 
    text-align: center;
    width: 96px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `team_member` class in css to `text-align:center`.

Try set to "teamMemberLink" class width: 96px;

it works for me here:
http://jsfiddle.net/has5V/1/

Or do you need to be link longer than 96px?

Ok, and do you really need to be elements floated?
Look here for another solution with br tags
http://jsfiddle.net/has5V/2/

Comment: the link can be longer than 96px - this is the problem... the link's text depends on the value from the database...

Comment: Did not you say that link should be longer than 96px? Can someone explain me why is winning answer better than my answers?